# Infrastructure monitoring using collectd with Graphite and Grafana

Tags: collectd

I am using `collectd` to gather metrics for system performance and MySQL and display in Grafana. I have done it now and I want to monitor the web server and services. I am facing some issues. Is there any other way to monitor them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to enable mod_status, collectd can scrape that page to provide web server metrics:

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Apache

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate, you can use the collectd MySQL plugin for the storage of data in MySQL. Please see https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:MySQL

**However**, I would recommend a more robust solution using InfluxDB as the datastore software since it is designed to work with high I/O loads.

Check out this guide, was very useful to me: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/monitoring-collectd-influxdb-grafana-alan-wen (no, I'm not the author.)